# Shortcut for hide a tool window in Intellij IDEA (Shift + Escape) is not working

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Intellij IDEA 13.1.5 and I cannot hide tool windows with default <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> keyboard shortcut. When I tried to set a different shortcut to the action, I figured out that Settings window cannot detect the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> key combination. (I can set a different key combination in settings, but cannot set <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, IDEA doesn't detect it)

What could be the problem here? Could this be an issue with the OS (I am on Windows 7) so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> is not sent to IDEA?

Comment: Shift-Esc is not used as a system shortcut in Windows 7, but it's likely that you have an application running that uses Shift-Esc as a global shortcut, thus preventing IntelliJ IDEA from handling it.

Comment: Killed processes one by one in task manager and after killing a process related to intel (can't remember the exact name), shortcut started to work. Even after a system restart still it works!.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was caused by a process named `PrivacyIconClient.exe` which should be using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> as a global shortcut. This process is started by `PIconStartup.exe` which is started at system startup and can be prevented from starting by unchecking it in `msconfig`.

Comment: `PrivacyIconClient.exe` is a part of Intel Management and Security Status.

Answer (score 3):

Privacy Icon Client can actually be configured to use shortcut another than default <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: AFAIK you can only configure it to `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `F1-F12` keys in any combination with `Ctrl`, `Alt` and `Shift`, and you can't remove the hotkey configuration in itself... But at least this is good alternative.